# Alternatives to checkbox for PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

Good morning,

I'm really just looking for advice here, I have a form that allows an admin user to select whether or not a regular user has access to something, initially I had planned to use a checkbox to deal with this but there doesn't seem to be any way to check in POST if the checkbox is UNCHECKED, which in this case would basically mean things the user CAN access, then things that are checked are things the user will NOT have access to.

After writing this out I'm now wondering if toggle radio buttons would be a better option, as it would basically return a value either way?

Any help would be appreciated!

here is an example of the HTML I am using within the form. So I basically need to know both states of each checkbox, whether checked or unchecked.

```
<div class=\"checkbox checkbox-danger\"> 
    <input id=".$row['UserID']." value=".$row['UserID']." name=\"staff[]\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"styled\"> 
    <label for=".$row['UserID'].">".$row['UserName']."</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: You check for a checkboxes existance to know if its checked. `if (!isset($_POST['cb']){ // not checked}`

Comment: The issue I have is that I've no way of knowing the name or ID of the checkbox as it's an array and will change in each case.

Comment: *"there doesn't seem to be any way to check in POST if the checkbox is UNCHECKED"* -- yes, it is. An unchecked checkbox is not sent to the server when the form is submitted. A checked checkbox is sent to the server. The value sent is not important, as long as the checkbox' name is in the posted data, the checkbox was checked when the form was submitted.

Comment: Maybe you should give us an example of the HTML that you are using for these checkboxes and the issues you think you have

Comment: Yes, sorry, here is an example of the HTML I am using within the form. So I basically need to know both states of each checkbox, whether checked or unchecked.

`<div class=\"checkbox checkbox-danger\">
                                                        <input id=".$row['UserID']." value=".$row['UserID']." name=\"staff[]\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"styled\">
                                                        <label for=".$row['UserID'].">".$row['UserName']."</label>
                                                        </div>`

Comment: For future reference: Nobody can read code in a comment, so use the EDIT link under the question and add things to the question itself